Administrator can add content for other users?
Administrator users have the permission to view/edit/delete contents created by these users.
Can administrator users create content for another user from the administrator back end?

The author of content is driven by a field in the Authoring Information Tab on the content's edit screen. You can set this field to be any user, and that user will be considered the Owner of the content for permissions purposes. By default this field gets populated with the current user.

This is the correct answer for stock Drupal.

My content is not a node content.It is an entity type content.So i cant change the authoring information.As you suggested i have use "Masquerade" module.Now my issue is solved.Thanks a lot....

Well, the question said 'content' and is tagged with nodes. Whether it is a custom entity or not, you can attach a UID property to it and mimic the 'authored' field on a node, and access checks to respect that.
